Reload javascript function after Ajax action
I had to add reviews on each product in the category(shop) page. The reviews are from flowbox. So I got a div and javascript.
<div id="flowbox-stars-widget-[product-id]"></div>
This div I can easily add to each product. But because I use woocommerce and JetWoobuilder for the shop page, I can not add the javascript per product the same way. So I am using a php function for that:
//Reviews op Categorie
function insert_product_review_scripts() {
    if (!is_product_category()) {
        return; // Not a product category page, do nothing
    }

    // Get the current category object based on the current query
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
    if (!$current_category || !isset($current_category->term_id)) {
        return; // No valid category found, do nothing
    }

    $args = array(
        'status' => 'publish',
        'limit' => -1, // Retrieve all products
        'category' => array($current_category->slug),
    );

    $products = wc_get_products($args);

    // Outputting a JavaScript function that can be called dynamically
    echo "<script>
            function loadProductReviews() {";
    
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        echo "window.flowboxReviews('init', {
                    container: '#flowbox-stars-widget-" . $product_id . "',
                    key: 'key',
                    productId: '" . $product_id . "',
                    locale: 'nl-NL'
                });";
    }

    echo "}
    window.onload = loadProductReviews;
          </script>";
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_product_review_scripts');  

At first everything was looking good until I clicked on the next page, everytime that I use something related to an ajax call it does not work anymore. Because the div from the product was not present when the javascript function was called.
For the pagination I use JetFilter.  I also tried to reload the javascript everytime that the DOM changed, but it ended up loading forever. I also tried to reload the function everytime that an AJAX call is made, but it loads all the time, even when I don't click on the next page.
